# C++ Best way to quickly read from larger file

Tags: c++

During runtime I frequently need to read small portions of larger file (300 mb).
Currently I always open up the file, read from it and then close it again like that:

```
FILE *file =fopen(szFileName,"rb");
if (file)
{
    fseek( file,iFirstByteToRead, SEEK_SET);
    fread(nEncodedBytes,sizeof(unsigned char), iLenCompressedBytes, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

But that is too slow because I do that so frequently. 
Also I am not sure if fread could be sped up.

What is the best practice for such a situation, please?

Comment: You can't do much about that. The reason is that seeking position in large file and reading from disk are very slow operations comparing to memory access. And the file is too large - optimal is 64/128 Mb (as Google proved in their data banks). Moreover, if you do it frequently, you risk to damage disk soon.

Comment: this is not C++ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the file open and you'll do much better.

Try `mmap` for improved performance still.

Comment: I once read about the CreateFileMapping function. Would that help additionally? Or what is that good for?

Comment: It's the Windows equivalent of mmap.

Answer (score 0):

The work related to file control always causes expensive cost. If you control several times for manage the file, you don’t have to close file pointer.

Like below, once you get the file pointer,

```
FILE *stream = fopen(stream, “rb”);

if (stream != NULL)
```

You have to close stream file pointer after finishing in your program, and also if you have to manage a number of files, you would use a thread, which is dedicated as a file reading.